# More granular data tables

Tags: data-model

How does Salesforce data modelling work in backend when there is one field in a table (Say for e.g. WhatId in Task & Event, UserorGroupID in AccountShare which can look up to a field in multiple table such as Account, Opportunity, etc for WhatId and User, Group for UserorGroupID. Similar for RecordType object's Id field. When Id field is selected, how does it know which table (ACcount, Campaign, Case...) to look at?

In terms of Data Model design, how does the relationship look like for fields such as WhatId, and UserGroupID to point in a correct table?

Is there any other table behind the scene to make this work?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's tough to say how exactly Salesforce has implemented the polymorphic fields that they present, the best example being the whatid/whoid you mentioned. It could be a set of tables in the backend that help present what we see on the front as the whatid relationship from a task to a account/case etc. etc. Obviously it doesn't make sense for Salesforce to make this information available, so it's more important to focus on what you do have access too. In that regard, what I've learned from working with Salesforce as opposed to true databases, is that Salesforce truly is an abstraction of a database, with a lot of what we see as a "object" really would have to be multiple tables on the backend. Of course this is all done in the end, to deliver a database that doesn't require data modeling expertise, computer science knowledge etc. to build a basic to even slightly advanced CRM.

Hopefully that helps a little bit,

--KC

Comment: I do know that there's at least two tables for every object that has custom fields: a table for all standard fields, plus at least one additional table for custom fields. This was covered in one of their videos about "skinny tables." A skinny table is a third optional table that improves performance for certain common queries and is built by support to support these queries. It's built by customer request, and is specialized to their organization's data. Of course, share tables, tag tables, etc are other related tables, but may be multiple physical tables.

Comment: @sfdcfox  I am trying to implement this data model in Qlikview and it's turning out to be quite a challenge. Thanks for your comment.